# WebView code generating Uncaught TypeError and Uncaught ReferenceError errors on Android 4.4.2 (API 19) emulator

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-emulator, mathjax

I'm having a problem with my code when running on a Android 4.4.2 KitKat (API 19) emulator...

When I emulate my project on a Android 4.3 (API 18) emulator, it works normally and creates the mathematical expressions with MathJax:

[Image of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xavDI.jpg)

But when I use a Android 4.4.2 emulator, the app don't work correctly:

[Image of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Mmb.jpg)

Here is the code of my project:

```
package com.testes.testesapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int exampleIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://test", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                              + "MathJax.Hub.Config({ " 
                              + "showMathMenu: false, "
                              + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
                              + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], " 
                              + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                              + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
                              // + "'SVG' : { blacker: 30, "
                              // + "styles: { path: { 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges' } } } "
                              + "});</script>"
                              + "<script type='text/javascript' "
                              + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                              + "></script>"
                              + "<span id='math'></span>","text/html","utf-8","");
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        edit.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        edit.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        edit.setText("");
        Button btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        btnShow.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnExample = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExample);
        btnExample.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private String doubleEscapeTeX(String s) {
        String t="";
        for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '\'') t += '\\';
            if (s.charAt(i) != '\n') t += s.charAt(i);
            if (s.charAt(i) == '\\') t += "\\";
        }
        return t;
    }

    private String getExample(int index) {
        return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tex_examples)[index];
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == findViewById(R.id.btnShow)) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                            + doubleEscapeTeX(edit.getText().toString()) + "\\\\]';");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        }
        else if (v == findViewById(R.id.btnClear)) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            edit.setText("");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='';");
        }
        else if (v == findViewById(R.id.btnExample)) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            edit.setText(getExample(exampleIndex++));
            if (exampleIndex > getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tex_examples).length - 1) 
                exampleIndex=0;
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                            + doubleEscapeTeX(edit.getText().toString()) + "\\\\]';");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        }
    }

}
```

When I press the "Example" or the "Show" button, LogCat emits the errors:

```
I/chromium(1254): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://test/ (1)
I/chromium(1254): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://test/ (1)
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem, and would like somebody's help to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this problem too.

Here is my solution:

1. change your base URL from `"http://test"` to `"http://test/"`
2. change this code `webView.loadUrl(..)` to `webView.evaluateJavascript(..);`. Especially for code where we want to load innerHTML. Don't forget to add anotation `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)` because it's only for Android 4.4 and above
3. never put `webView.loadWithBaseUrl(..)` in the same process with `webView.loadUrl(..)`. Because If `webView.loadUrl(..)` was loaded before `webView.loadWithBaseUrl(..)` finished, it will raise error as OP stated above.

For number 3, your codes is already conform with this (because in your codes, `webView.loadUrl(..)` execution was already separated with `webView.loadWithBaseUrl(..)` by using `OnClick` event. So, don't pay attention to it.

But if your apps need to load them at one event, consider to separate them by using this code: 
`

```
private void initiateWebView(){

    webViewEquationDisplay.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
                loadUrlKitKat(equationSymbolFinal+equationToBeDisplayedFinal);
            }
            else{
                webViewEquationDisplay.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='<font color=\"yellow\">`"+equationToBeDisplayedFinal+"`</font>';");
            }

            webViewEquationDisplay.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        }
    });

    final String mathJaxOfflineUrl = "file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js";            
    webViewEquationDisplay.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
            +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ " 
                +"showMathMenu: false, "
                +"jax: ['input/AsciiMath','output/HTML-CSS'], "
                +"extensions: ['asciimath2jax.js'], " 
                +"AsciiMath: { fixphi: true, useMathMLspacing: true, displaystyle: false, decimalsign: \".\" }, "
              +"});</script>"
            +"<script type='text/javascript' "
              +"src='"+mathJaxOfflineUrl+"'"
              +"></script><span id='math'></span>","text/html","utf-8","");
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void loadUrlKitKat(String param){
    webViewEquationDisplay.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='<font color=\"#97FD97\">`"+param+"`</font>';",null);
}
```

`

good luck

Comment: This is the best answer for the KitKat problem!  Thanks, Dimas

Comment: what is "equationSymbolFinal" mentioned in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I moved different javascript functions out of the main page to an separate .js file. For some reason, Android can't find externally-loaded JavaScript webview functions from Java - only the ones in the main page. Once I moved the function back from the JS file, it immediately started working.

Try making a "proxy" function like this directly inside the main HTML:

```
function proxy() {
    call_some_other_function_from_JS_file();
}
```

This worked for me. I'm sure there must be a way to get find these functions, because I didn't have this problem on iOS. Someone please comment if you know a better way.

Comment: Figure out this problem, solved it. using:- If the app targets LOLLIPOP or above the default web view behaviour is to completely deny mixed content. As mobile connect requires the use of HTTP during header enrichment we need a more relaxed security setting.                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_‌CONTENT_COMPATIBILIT‌Y_MODE); }

Answer (score 0):

webview.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='`"+doubleEscapeTeX(questn)+"`';",null);

webview.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");

This is the sollution for api 19 or above